# How to write a query to get data within a period range?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a employee table with columns like

```
emp_id, firstname, lastname, month  and year.
```

Now I need to get *employees* from table between **jan 2012** and **march 2012**.
In columns *month* and *year* we are storing "1" for jan and "3" for march i.e. month numbers and year column has year like *2012*.
Please help.

Comment: Tip: Oracle has a DATE datatype, where you should store your month and year columns in just one column of that datatype. Just set the day to 1 and the hour, minute and seconds to 0. Your queries will be much easier and you can better index that new column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Employees between Januar and March 2012:

```
select * from employee
where year = 2012 and month between 1 and 3
```

Employees between Januar 2012 and March 2013:

```
select * from employee
where (year = 2012 and month between 3 and 12)
or (year = 2013 and month between 1 and 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what if I need to get data between march 2012 to march 2013?

Comment: I will have four inputs like start_month, start_year, end_month and end_year to the where clause. This will be based on user selection.

Comment: @Ahish select * from employee
where (year BETWEEN start_year AND end_year and month between start_month and end_month) OR (year>start_year AND year<end_year)

Comment: @JonasT That wouldn't work for the range Oct 2011 to March 2013.

Comment: @yhw42(year>start_year AND year<end_year) will return true for Oct 2011 to March 2013.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  employee
WHERE to_char(year,0000) + to_char(month,00) BETWEEN '201201' AND '201203'
```

Comment: This query is giving me "missing expression" error in the where clause.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't aware you are using Oracle. My query is working fine in SQL, and you can take the concept, which is combine the year and month to be a string formatted in YYYYMM, then compare to your value

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be best off converting everything to datetime before doing the selection.  I personally would prefer a single datetime column instead of seperate 'month' and 'year' columns, but if you can't go that way, something like this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM employees 
 WHERE CAST( CAST(year AS VARCHAR(4)) +
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
            '00'
            AS DATETIME)
BETWEEN
    CAST( CAST(start_year AS VARCHAR(4)) +
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(start_month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
            '00'
            AS DATETIME)
AND
    CAST( CAST(end_year AS VARCHAR(4)) +
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(end_month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
            '00'
            AS DATETIME)
```

It's kind of ugly, unfortunately.  Maybe it could be cleaned up by converting the start and end dates to datetime before the selection statement and storing them in variables?

Answer (score -1):

Hi this might help you,

```
 select * from emp
where to_date(concat('1-',concat(concat(month,'-'), year)),'DD-MM-YY') 
      between to_date('1-&month-&year' ,'DD-MM-YY') 
and   to_date('1-&month-&year' ,'DD-MM-YY') ;
```

i'm converting every month and year value to a data of specified format and comparing them.